# How can I find out images used in a Windows tool without having its source code?

Tags: windows

Well, the title describes my problem pretty well. Hope somone can help me?

Some more information about the program:
It's an old program with a .exe execute-File, a UIF-File at the same directory, temp and a Data-Folder there as well. But I can't find the logo somewhere in there. I guess it's in the .exe-File (4.4 MB big) – is there a way to extract it?

Comment: Have you considered taking a screenshot?

Comment: The images may be hardcoded in the sources, in that case, there may be no better way to get them instead of taking screenshots.

Answer (score 2):

See if you can dig it up with [ResHack](http://www.angusj.com/resourcehacker).

> Resource HackerTM is a freeware utility to view, modify, rename, add,
>   delete and extract resources in 32bit & 64bit Windows executables and
>   resource files (*.res). It incorporates an internal resource script
>   compiler and decompiler and works on all (Win95 - Win7) Windows
>   operating systems.
>
> Viewing Resources: Cursor, Icon, Bitmap, GIF, AVI, and JPG resource
>   images can be viewed. WAV and MIDI audio resources can be played.
>   Menus, Dialogs, MessageTables, StringTables, Accelerators, Delphi
>   Forms, and VersionInfo resources can be viewed as decompiled resource
>   scripts. Menus and Dialogs can also be viewed as they would appear in
>   a running application.

Comment: Thanks for that – that helps with the Icon. But still can't find other pics ...

Comment: Images are often placed in DLLs loaded by the main program. Search them too for resources.

Comment: Care to elaborate on what ResHack does?